# Proving that there is a number starting with $1$ among $17^n,17^{n+1},17^{n+2},17^{n+3},17^{n+4}$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

> Prove that for $\forall n \in \mathbb N_+$, there is a number starting with digit $1$ among $17^n,17^{n+1},17^{n+2},17^{n+3},17^{n+4}$.

I have found out, by observing the first few terms of powers of $17$, that

- If $17^k$ begins with digit $3,4$, then $17^{k-2}$ begins with digit $1$.
- If $17^k$ begins with digit $5,6,7,8$, then $17^{k-3}$ begins with digit $1$.
- If $17^k$ begins with digit $9$, then $17^{k-3}$ begins with digit $1$.
- If $17^k$ begins with digit $2$, then $17^{k-4}$ begins with digit $1$.

If we can prove these, then the problem is solved.

Comment: Hint: $\beta:=\log_{10}1.7\approx 0.23045$. If $\alpha:=\log_{10}17^n$ you are to prove that one of the numbers $\alpha+k\beta, k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ has a fractional part between zero and $\log_{10}2\approx0.30103$.

Comment: Presumably it should be powers of $17$ everywhere. I don't see what the powers of $16$ have anything to do with this exercise.